# Is there a way to instantiate an mocked object of type DecodedJWT in java?

Tags: java, spring, auth0

I am trying to test a logic to decode a JWT token and want to create an instance of DeocdedJWT that can be used for mocking. Is that a possibility in Java?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That said `DeocdedJWT` is an interface so you can create your own implementation or use something like [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/). But, there is no way to answer this question unless we see your code.